# Identify specific Android device hardware from website

Tags: android, identity, event-tracking

I'm deploying a large number of Android devices for a project which are owned and controlled by me, including with a Mobile Device Management system.

I don't know how to identify the devices when the device is being used to log into our web-based services. We can know *who* logs in, obviously, but not what device they are coming from.

Ideally we would know the IMEI or Serial of a device when it logs in, but it can really be **any** unique identifier

I 100% understand why this information is not typically available to a website -- it's easy enough for advertisers and other to track people! However in our case, we own both the endpoints AND the website, so it seems like something should be possible.

Typically our devices clear the cache on the browser when they reboot, so it likely can't be something based on the cache, but I could explore more options here and see whether it's possible to disable this.

The website is based on React, if that's helpful. However, we could use another page built on whatever makes this easier if needed.

We do also have native Android apps running on the device, but I don't know if we can pull information from them into the browser somehow.

Note that we've tried using the WebRTC method to grab internal IP addresses, which works to some extent but is not ideal since it's inconsistent and is blocked on later versions of Android's browsers. Also if the device changes IP, that method no longer helps.